# Crypto wallet for Ethereum

Tags: cryptocurrency

I'm new to crypto and I'm looking for a crypto wallet with the following features:

1. it's 100% FOSS (I don't trust entering my pass into closed source code)
2. it's non-custodial
3. EDIT: <strike>it's hierarchical deterministic</strike> I was asking for this because I assumed HD wallets could provide real privacy, but it turns out that's not the case with any public blockchain alone, be it BTC or ETH or others, so I strip this requirement as I don't need it anymore.
4. it is available as desktop application for Linux or it reportedly runs somehow on desktop Linux
5. it supports ETH

I've already looked around, but I'm having hard time finding one that meets all those requirements. Other features I'd like it to have, but that are not a strict requirement, are:

1. ERC20 tokens and DApps support
2. BTC support

Is there anything like that?

Comment: I'm not sure about 2-4, but I use https://airgap.it/, it's FOSS, supports ETH - I'm sure you'll be able to determine if it has the other features. I likes the simplicity + security of it. Sorry if not what you were looking for. I'm not really versed in Crypto that deep. You might also want to refer to: https://alternativeto.net/category/cryptocurrencies/cryptocurrency-wallet/?license=opensource&platform=linux

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about airgap. It also has feature 2 and maybe 4 (there is a link to the Linux version, but then I could not find it at the linked page). I'll try it out to check if it meets #3 too.

Comment: You are right about the links, strange. They do have a live [bootable CD linux distro](https://github.com/airgap-it/airgap-distro). I know they have an active [Telegram](https://t.me/AirGap) community, maybe ask there about Linux installation.

Answer (score 0):

After having edited my question, the answer becomes quite simple, as there are probably a ton wallets that provide the edited list of features.

Just now I'm trying out Atomic Wallet, but I'm not inclined to accept my answer unless it will remain the only answer for a while, as I can't really recommend a software I don't know yet.

EDIT: Atomic Wallet [isn't 100% FOSS](https://support.atomicwallet.io/article/184-why-is-atomic-wallet-not-open-source), so I can't accept my own answer. Besides, I'm also trying to move to something else.

Comment: I think at this point you can safely accept your own answer, but besides, can you add a link to the proposed program and some details about it?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I just forgot about my question and answer.